# Can we increase the height of tooltip anchor in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

Please find the image below.
[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkbyU.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option directly available from the API. You can try to create your own HTML tooltip or change indicator values in the core.

API References:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML